# Check for dropdown and input values on search submit

Tags: jquery

I know that this question has been asked before in other threads, but I am having trouble implementing the solutions I have found for my particular case. I would like to prompt alerts in JQuery if two search fields have not been filled out when the search button is clicked. My attempts are not working, but I am not sure whether it is a syntax issue or an implementation issue. Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks.

Here is a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6050/

```
$('#searchsubmit').on('click', function() {
   $('#facetwp-location').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            alert('Please enter a location');
        }
        });
    if ($(".facetwp-dropdown").val() === "") {
             alert('Please choose a category');
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code indentation is your best friend!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#searchsubmit').on('click', function() {
       $('#facetwp-location').change(function() {
            if($(this).val() == '') {
                alert('Please enter a location');
            }
        });
        if ($(".facetwp-dropdown").val() === "") {
            alert('Please choose a category');
        }  
    }); // <-- Here is the problem, you don't close the on click event.
});
```

[Edited JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6051/)

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that now myself, after playing with the JSFiddle. And sorry for the messy indentation, I wasn't careful copying it :)